TS2345: Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<void | AddItem, ItemInput, AsyncThunkConfig>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'
In my slice, I have defined the action to be as follows:
https://github.com/jasonabanico/RedGranite/blob/main/src/Client/RedGranite.Client.Web/src/app/containers/ItemPage/itemPageSlice.ts
export const addItem = createAsyncThunk(
    'itemPage/addItem',
    async (itemInput: ItemInput) => {
        return await itemService
            .addItem(itemInput)
            .catch((err: any) => {
                console.log("Error:", err);
            });
    },
)

I have also defined useAppDispatch as:
https://github.com/jasonabanico/RedGranite/blob/main/src/Client/RedGranite.Client.Web/src/app/hooks.ts
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

I use both of the above like so:
https://github.com/jasonabanico/RedGranite/blob/main/src/Client/RedGranite.Client.Web/src/app/containers/ItemPage/addItemPage.tsx
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
...
dispatch(addItem(itemInput));

I am getting the following error:

TS2345: Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<void | AddItem, ItemInput, AsyncThunkConfig>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
21 |             longDescription
22 |         };

23 |         dispatch(addItem(itemInput));
|                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
24 |     };


What is wrong with my definitions? Why can't I use addItem in dispatch?
UPDATE:
Code in repo updated to this, but getting same error.
export const useAppDispatch = useDispatch.withTypes<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector = useSelector.withTypes<RootState>();

UPDATE:
To replicate in Codesandbox.

Open terminal
cd src
cd Client
cd RedGranite.Client.Web
npm install
npm run build
see build error


I finally found the the reason.
That was because you defined middleware separately with any type in store.ts.
So I fixed your issue by adjusting your store.ts file like this:
    import {
      configureStore,
      ThunkAction,
      Action
    } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import homePageReducer from "./containers/HomePage/homePageSlice";
    import itemPageReducer from "./containers/ItemPage/itemPageSlice";
    import ReduxLogger from "redux-logger";
    
    export const store = configureStore({
      middleware:(getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware().concat(ReduxLogger),
      reducer: {
        homePage: homePageReducer,
        itemPage: itemPageReducer,
      },
    });
    
    export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
    export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
    export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
      ReturnType,
      RootState,
      unknown,
      Action<string>
    >;


The type of AppDispatch should be ThunkDispatch<any, undefined, UnknownAction> & Dispatch<UnknownAction>, but it was just Dispatch<UnknownAction>. So it didn't work. It's due to type of getDefaultMiddleware was any.

According to current documentation it would seem your useAppDispatch and useAppSelector hooks aren't quite right.


For useSelector, it saves you the need to type (state: RootState) every time

For useDispatch, the default Dispatch type does not know about thunks. In order to correctly dispatch thunks, you need to use the
specific customized AppDispatch type from the store that includes
the thunk middleware types, and use that with useDispatch. Adding a
pre-typed useDispatch hook keeps you from forgetting to import
AppDispatch where it's needed.
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = useDispatch.withTypes<AppDispatch>()
export const useAppSelector = useSelector.withTypes<RootState>()




Update your src/Client/RedGranite.Client.Web/src/app/hooks.ts file to the current suggestion:
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store';

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = useDispatch.withTypes<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector = useSelector.withTypes<RootState>();


I updated my dependencies so that it can use withTypes. The error is still there but message changed to: "Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<void | AddItem, ItemInput, AsyncThunkConfig>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnknownAction'."

when i mouse-over the AppDispatch definition in VS code, I see "type AppDispatch = Dispatch"

@JonasArcangel Can you try to create a running Codesandbox demo of your frontend code that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live? If necessary, please also include exact reproduction steps.

It is a build error so I can't run it. I have provided the Codesandbox link and steps above.

It seems you are returning wrong data in your action function.
So I think it should be like this:

export const addItem = createAsyncThunk(
  "itemPage/addItem",
  async (itemInput: ItemInput, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const data = await itemService.addItem(itemInput);
      return data;
    } catch (error: any) {
      // if there is an error, it would get rejected status in your extraReducer function
      if (error.response.data) return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);


Hope this can be helpful.

I'm still getting the same build error with this update.

@JonasArcangel, if you want your project redux works properly somehow, I can provide another redux structure.

what do you suggest
